# VideoJS post frame play button firing on touch behind modal and fixed footer

Tags: touch, html5-video, event-propagation

I have a site where I have a videojs video embedded in the page. Also on the page I have a fixed footer and occasionally a modal window overlay that appears on click of a link. All works great on desktops but on mobile devices the touch events on .vjs-big-play-button are firing when the video is behind the fixed footer OR when behind the modal.

I've dealt with this before and I think solved it but I can't seem to figure out how to prevent it. has anyone come across this. I'm not having much luck finding a solution in my research on the internets :)

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 0):

The iPad browser does this weird thing where all touch or click events get captured by a video element, regardless of what's on top of it, whenever the video element's native controls are enabled. There isn't really anything you can do with the script to get around this, except to disable the native controls and build your own.

Video.js comes with custom controls instead of the native controls, except when running on the iPad, because ([according to heff](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/510)):

> It was intentional choice to use the native controls on mobile for now, because the HTML controls need some polish before they're fully useable. We have a version of the skin that works well on mobile and we'll get some of those changes ported over soon.

So you need to force Video.js to use the HTML controls, which I believe you can do by setting the `nativeControlsForTouch` option, like so:

```
<video class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-my-personal-skin" controls preload="auto" data-setup="{nativeControlsForTouch: true}"></video>
```

Note the addition of the `controls` attribute and the option in `data-setup`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. Using nativeControlsForTouch actually left the native look and functionality exactly the same and the desktop view now had a control bar below it. I thought maybe it would be an option but when I tried to test it on my phone I could still click through to the video from behind the fixed footer. I was able to partially solve my problem by hiding the video when the modal is opened. I still have this problem when the video is behind the fixed footer. I guess I could hide the video (replaced with a fake poster frame when the video is at a certain X position. Hmm.

Comment: Sorry, I think I screwed up. try nativeControlsForTouch: false

Comment: Let me know if that works, and I'll update the answer.

Comment: No I'm sorry that was the same result. I was still able to click through the fixed footer to the video behind it. Thanks for suggesting a solution but unfortunately that didnt work.